# Not able to pass url in Edge Browser using Selenium

Tags: selenium, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I am am trying to launch IE Edge Browser . Window launched but url is not getting passed. ie code gets stuck at `driver = new EdgeDriver()`. thread is not moving to `driver.get("www.google.com")`

Microsoft Edge             : 25.10586.372.0
  Microsoft EdgeHTML         : 13.10586
Microsoft Windows Version  : 1511 (OS Build 10586.39)
Selenium                   : 3.6
MicrosoftWebDriver Version : 10.0.10586.0

**Code**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","C:\\Eclipse\\Drivers\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");

WebDriver ed = new EdgeDriver();

ed.get("hhtp://www.google.com");
```

**ERROR**
**Error Came after closing the Edge Browser**

Comment: Can share your code attempt?

Comment: System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","D:\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
WebDriver ed = new EdgeDriver();
ed.get("hhtp://www.google.com");

Comment: Please update the Question with your code block and the complete error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB , i am not able to paste the error stack trace in the question.

Comment: (JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$24(ProtocolHandshake.java:359)
 at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)